# How does one make arrow keys on number inputs lazy in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Vue supports lazy binding to models with the `lazy` modifier, e.g.

```
<input v-model.lazy="value" />
```

Now the model isn't updated until the input loses focus. However, if I change the type to `Number` and use the arrow keys to set the value, the model updates while the input has focus:

```
<input type="number" v-model.lazy="value" />
```

Is there an (easy) way to delay binding until after focus is lost?

Comment: Do you mean arrow keys on keyboard or input?

Comment: The arrow keys specifically; typing numbers in the input box behaves as expected. What do you mean "input"?

Comment: There are arrow buttons inside number input, too. Do they work differently from arrow keys on keyboard? Any way, I guess this is specific to browser implementation and you'll need to handle quick changes in input focus if you want this to behave differently

Comment: .lazy updates model after 'change' event, not only after loosing focus. I guess the arrow keys fire change event internally. If you need to update after change event of blur event, put you code there instead of using v-model in this situation.

Comment: @EstusFlask I see what you're asking now. Both behave the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` is synonymous for `:value` + `@change`. Assuming the arrows on input trigger a focus event, you can try replacing `v-model` with `:value` and `@blur` pair. Might not work if `.lazy` modifier already does this.

`<input type="number" :value="value" @blur="value = $event.target.value" />`

Another alternative is to "debounce" the change event with a set time so the value doesn't update while the user is changing the value.

**Edit: debounce example using npm package**

After installing and importing the `debounce` package, you need to create/assign the "debounced" version of the method (should define it in methods) to a method name under `created` (can be a different method name but should match what you put in @blur listener.

`<input type="number" :value="value" @blur="updateValueOnBlur" />`

```
created() {
  this.updateValueOnBlur = debounce(this.updateValueOnBlur, 500);
},
methods: {
  updateValueOnBlur(e) {
    this.value = e.target.value;
  },
}
```

Comment: How would you debounce the change event?

Comment: @ChrisCamaratta I updated the answer with an example on how to use the debounce library. There are ways to do it without a library but this is the most straightforward.